# XAML Binding data of an XML attribute and displaying its value

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, rss, xmlserializer

I am making simple RSS reader for Windows Phone which reads an XML file using XML Serializer and displays the list of items. I have Rss.css file and amongst others I have item class (below fragment):

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

And I am binding data in XAML files and displaying e.g. title field like this:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Rss.Channel.Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
```

etc., and it's working fine. Now, let's say that in the XML title has an attribute, e.g. short="true".
How do I bind and display this attribute?

I tried to create another class under Item class:

```
public class Title
{
    [XmlAttribute("short")]
    public string Short { get; set; }

}
```

and simply bind the attribute like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title.Short}"/>
```

but it's not working. Can I "reach" it in XAML somehow or should I change something in the .cs file?

PS. The given example is a shorter alternative to my problem therefore it is not necessarily very logical.

Comment: You should be able to achieve this by using an XPath-binding. Something like this:  `<TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Short}"/>`

Comment: I guess you meant {Binding Path=@Short} as compilator says there's no such property as "XPath" for binding but nevertheless it still doesn't work.

Comment: You should be able to saw this problem in half with some debugging.  Either the problem is the XML isn't deserialized correctly (`Short` is `null`), or the binding isn't working correctly (`Short` has a value but it's not bound to the UI).  Which is it?

Comment: I have this error in Debug Output when I run the app with line _<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title.Short}"/>_ : Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Short' property not found on 'String'.

Comment: If you're binding to `Title.Short` and the context is `Item`, then where's it magically going to get `Short` from?  `Title` is a `string` - your error points this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding to something that doesn't exist - `Title` is a `string` in your model.  You should change this so the deserialization can give you both the title and the attribute:

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public Title Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
}

public class Title
{
    [XmlAttribute("short")]
    public string Short { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then your current `Title` binding changes to `Title.Value` and your `Title.Short` binding should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, it indeed works however I needed it for extracting url from this marker: `<media:thumbnail url="http://12345.jpg"/>` and strangely in this case it doesn't work. Could the colon be the problem? In item I have `[XmlElement(media:thumbnail)] public MediaThumbnail MediaThumbnail { get; set; }` and below I have MediaThumbnail class with url attribute.

Comment: No, `media` is a namespace prefix.  Somewhere you will have an `xmlns:media="http://example.com/` attribute.  The `XmlElement` attribute should include this, e.g. `[XmlElement("thumbnail", Namespace = "http://example.com/")]`